# Cannot register user Unpermitted parameters error with devise and devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am on Rails3.2 devise_invitable (1.1.8), devise (3.1.1) WITHOUT strong parameter, when I try to register a user I get following log. I am using this route to custom the devise invitation controller:

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, :controllers => { :invitations => 'team_invitations' }
```

But why the registration request send to the DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController instead of the devise registration controller

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-02 21:27:50 +1300
Processing by DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"thlkjyVYHhFY3erB+9yI7uwotIU7GozswOdjz9w7DNA=", 
"user"=>{"username"=>"", "email"=>"boopage@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: username, email, password
```

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

I had same issue come up.

Comment: Not yet.. Got an issue written here: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/387

Answer (score 2):

This is quite dated and I am more than certain none of the solutions provided above work right now (because, I ran into same issue).

Extend the controller for invitable and add the following lines of code to it:

```
#app/controllers/invitations_controllers.rb
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
def edit
   super
end

private
def update_resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :your_params, :invitation_token)
end
```

To extend the controller, you'll need to create the following:

```
#app/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { invitations: 'invitations' }
```

And voila!

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the strong parameters in your application controller: this will help https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#strong-parameters

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite) do |u|
   u.permit(username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
         :invitation_token)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in controllers/application_controller.rb add:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :email
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :password
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, above solutions are not working for me. So I did a little monkey-patching for devise module (source https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/a50e37bc43509f7be02be8bca2b072b55e66eeaf/lib/devise_invitable/parameter_sanitizer.rb):

```
module DeviseInvitable
  module ParameterSanitizer
    CUSTOM_FIELDS = [:field1, :field2]

    private

    if defined?(Devise::BaseSanitizer)
      def permit(keys)
        default_params.permit(*Array(keys))
      end

      def attributes_for_with_invitable(kind)
        case kind
        when :invite
          resource_class.respond_to?(:invite_key_fields) ? resource_class.invite_key_fields.concat(CUSTOM_FIELDS) : []
        when :accept_invitation
          [:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token]
        else attributes_for_without_invitable(kind)
        end
      end
    else
      def initialize_with_invitable(resource_class, resource_name, params)
        initialize_without_invitable(resource_class, resource_name, params)
        permit(:invite, keys: (resource_class.respond_to?(:invite_key_fields) ? resource_class.invite_key_fields.concat(CUSTOM_FIELDS) : []) )
        permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token] )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Just place it to initializers.